# How to use instanced struct values in a match statement?

Tags: syntax, rust

I have an example instanced struct, named args, of the original struct Args.

```
struct Args {
    arg1: bool,
    arg2: bool,
}
```

and the instanced struct being:

```
let args = Args {
    arg1: true,
    arg2: false,
}
```

Using these arguments, I am attempting to avoid a jumble of if-else statments and just use a `match` statement. However, when attempting to perform the following:

```
match true {
    args.arg1 => println!("Argument 1 is true!"),
    args.arg2 => println!("Argument 2 is true!"),
}
```

I am given the error

```
error: expected one of `=>`, `@`, `if`, or `|`, found `.`
  --> src/main.rs:13:13
   |
13 |         args.arg1 => println!("Argument one is true"),
   |             ^ expected one of `=>`, `@`, `if`, or `|` here

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Is there an escape character sequence I should use to avoid this, or is this simply incorrect syntax?

Comment: Does [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=1511d37835ea7de771be838147f6a8dd) help ?

Comment: It's good to know this is possible, but my production program is using several arguments, not two alone... Iterating over all possible combinations would be a  pain :/

Comment: I can't help you about something I can't see.

Comment: For example, instead of just arg1 and arg2, it has arg1 through arg10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear to me what you mean to happen for the case where you have both arg1 and arg2 set to `true` - do you just want the first branch of the if to be taken, or both?

If its both - then really you should just use multiple ifs.

```
if args.arg1 { println!("Argument 1 is true!") }
if args.arg2 { println!("Argument 2 is true!") }
```

If only one should occur preferring arg1, then you can use a [struct destructure](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/destructuring/destructure_structures.html)

```
match args {
    Args { arg1:true, ..} => println!("Argument 1 is true!"),
    Args { arg2:true, ..} => println!("Argument 2 is true!"),
    _ => println!("Neither is true")
}
```

You can use the match to match more complex cases too

```
match args {
   Args {arg1:true, arg2:false, ...} => println!("TF"),
}
```

However, if at most one argument can be true at once, you really have an enum and should probably handle it like

```
enum Arg {
  None,
  Arg1,
  Arg2
}

fn main() {
    let args:Args = get_argument();
    match args {
       Args::None => println!("none"),
       Args::Arg1 => println!("Argument 1 is true!"),
       Args::Arg2 => println!("Argument 2 is true!")
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a good point you raise! I created this with the expectation that only one arg would be true at once.

Comment: If only one is true at once, you really have an enum. I'll update the code to detail that too.

Comment: I haven't yet gotten to the Enums chapter of The Book yet; but your code is perfect in my situation.. thank you!!